# Big Query: converting a legacy sql request to a standard SQL request?

Tags: sql, error-handling, google-bigquery

This is my query: How to convert it into standard SQL please? Thank you so much for your help. I don't know of to do it.

```
SELECT date,
    max(case when customDimensions.index = 1 then customDimensions.value end) AS CUSTOMDIMENSIONS_VALUE, 
    visitNumber,
    fullvisitorid,
    visitStartTime,
    SEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(visitStartTime) AS humain,
    TIME (visitStartTime+3600 ) AS Paris_timezone,
    hits.hour,
    hits.minute,
    CONCAT(fullvisitorid, STRING(visitid)) AS sessionid,
    max(CASE WHEN hits.customDimensions.index = 11 THEN hits.customDimensions.value END) AS localproductname,
    device.deviceCategory,
    hits.page.pagePath,
    IFNULL(hits.page.pagePathLevel2, '') AS HITS_PAGE_PAGEPATHLEVEL2,
    IFNULL(hits.page.pagePathLevel3, '') AS HITS_PAGE_PAGEPATHLEVEL3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN hits.customDimensions.index = 14 THEN hits.customDimensions.value END) AS assetpurpose,
    hits.hitNumber,
FROM (FLATTEN([85801771.ga_sessions_20161025], customDimensions.value )),
  (FLATTEN([85801771.ga_sessions_20161026], customDimensions.value )),
WHERE customDimensions.value != "null" AND customDimensions.value = "968a9587-0614-4155-9597-bf17aef42125" AND hits.type = 'PAGE' AND (customDimensions.index = 1 OR hits.customDimensions.index = 11 OR hits.customDimensions.index = 14
    OR hits.customDimensions.index = 27 ) AND hits.page.hostname CONTAINS 'website.fr' AND hits.type = 'PAGE'
GROUP EACH BY DATE, visitStartTime, humain, Paris_timezone, hits.hour, hits.minute, fullVisitorId, sessionid, visitNumber, device.deviceCategory, hits.page.pagePath, HITS_PAGE_PAGEPATHLEVEL2, HITS_PAGE_PAGEPATHLEVEL3, hits.hitNumber,
LIMIT 100000
```

I try do translate it into standard sql but I got the following error:

> Syntax error: Unexpected floating point literal "85801771."

Maybe there are others mistakes in my query.

standard SQL:

```
SELECT date,
    max(case when customDimensions.index = 1 then customDimensions.value end) AS CUSTOMDIMENSIONS_VALUE, 
    visitNumber,
    fullvisitorid,
    visitStartTime,
    SEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(visitStartTime) AS humain,
    TIME (visitStartTime+3600 ) AS Paris_timezone,
    hits.hour,
    hits.minute,
    CONCAT(fullvisitorid, STRING(visitid)) AS sessionid,
    max(CASE WHEN hits.customDimensions.index = 11 THEN hits.customDimensions.value END) AS localproductname,
    device.deviceCategory,
    hits.page.pagePath,
    IFNULL(hits.page.pagePathLevel2, '') AS HITS_PAGE_PAGEPATHLEVEL2,
    IFNULL(hits.page.pagePathLevel3, '') AS HITS_PAGE_PAGEPATHLEVEL3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN hits.customDimensions.index = 14 THEN hits.customDimensions.value END) AS assetpurpose,
    hits.hitNumber,
FROM (FLATTEN([85801771.ga_sessions_20161025], customDimensions.value )),
  (FLATTEN([85801771.ga_sessions_20161026], customDimensions.value )),
WHERE customDimensions.value != "null" AND customDimensions.value = "968a9587-0614-4155-9597-bf17aef42125" AND hits.type = 'PAGE' AND (customDimensions.index = 1 OR hits.customDimensions.index = 11 OR hits.customDimensions.index = 14
    OR hits.customDimensions.index = 27 ) AND hits.page.hostname CONTAINS 'website.fr' AND hits.type = 'PAGE'
GROUP BY DATE, visitStartTime, humain, Paris_timezone, hits.hour, hits.minute, fullVisitorId, sessionid, visitNumber, device.deviceCategory, hits.page.pagePath, HITS_PAGE_PAGEPATHLEVEL2, HITS_PAGE_PAGEPATHLEVEL3, hits.hitNumber,
LIMIT 100000
```

Comment: Fer I try this  #standardSQL
SELECT 
  date,
  max(case when customDimensions.index = 1 then customDimensions.value end)  AS CUSTOMDIMENSIONS_VALUE, visitNumber,  fullvisitorid,  visitStartTime,  SEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(visitStartTime) AS humain,  TIME (visitStartTime+3600 ) AS Paris_timezone,  hits.hour,  hits.minute,

Comment: CONCAT(fullvisitorid, STRING(visitid)) AS sessionid,  
  max(case
      WHEN hits.customDimensions.index = 11 THEN hits.customDimensions.value END) AS localproductname,
  device.deviceCategory,
  hits.page.pagePath,
  IFNULL(hits.page.pagePathLevel2, '') AS HITS_PAGE_PAGEPATHLEVEL2,
  IFNULL(hits.page.pagePathLevel3, '') AS HITS_PAGE_PAGEPATHLEVEL3,
  MAX(CASE
      WHEN hits.customDimensions.index = 14 THEN hits.customDimensions.value END) AS assetpurpose,
  hits.hitNumber

Comment: FROM 
85801771.ga_sessions_
WHERE
 _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20161025' AND '20161026'
 customDimensions.value != "null"
  AND customDimensions.value = "968a9587-0614-4155-9597-bf17aef42125"
  AND hits.type = 'PAGE'
  AND (customDimensions.index = 1
    OR hits.customDimensions.index = 11
    OR hits.customDimensions.index = 14
    OR hits.customDimensions.index = 27 )
  AND hits.page.hostname CONTAINS 'XXX.fr'
  AND hits.type = 'PAGE'

Comment: GROUP BY
  DATE,
  visitStartTime,
  humain,
  Paris_timezone,
  hits.hour,
  hits.minute,
  fullVisitorId,
  sessionid,
  visitNumber,
  device.deviceCategory,
  hits.page.pagePath,
  HITS_PAGE_PAGEPATHLEVEL2,
  HITS_PAGE_PAGEPATHLEVEL3,
  hits.hitNumber,
LIMIT
  100000

Comment: and I got this error Syntax error: Unexpected floating point literal "85801771." at [15:1]

Comment: I suggest you to edit your question and add that error so anyone with enough knowledge can help you.

Comment: ok Fred Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of rewriting your query for you, it would probably be more useful to you in the long run to talk about some of the differences between legacy and standard SQL and point you toward documentation. Stepping through the parts of your query:

- `SEC_TO_TIMESTAMP` is equivalent to `TIMESTAMP_SECONDS`.
- `TIME` (with an INT64 in micros as input) is equivalent to `FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%H:%M:%S', TIMESTAMP_MICROS(micros))`.
- There is no `STRING` function, but you can use `CAST(expr AS STRING)`.
- `FLATTEN` is not a function in standard SQL. Instead, perform a [`CROSS JOIN` with the array](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql#removing_repetition_with_flatten).
- `CONTAINS` is not a function in standard SQL, but you can use `LIKE '%website.fr%'`.

Many of these differences are covered in the [migration guide](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql), which is a good starting point if you want to figure out how to translate a function or operator from legacy to standard SQL. You can read about the functions that I mentioned above in the [functions and operators documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators).

Comment: Thanks vadim for your kindly help. I Will Troy to use this basis also. Sebastien